# PHP And Reflection For Showing Available Formatters On A Report Column

Tags: php, reflection

I'm using reflection in PHP to load a list of available `Formatter` classes that all have methods that do formatting of a value in a specific CSV column.

e.g. for Phone numbers `input=5554443333` `output=(555) 444-3333`

Here are three formatters as well as the base class with a static method to find all of them and return the formatter function names as well as an "example" output of each.

Are there better ways to do this or generally is reflection just fine in this case? I personally like how simple it is to add additional formatters that just inherit from the base class.

The ugliest part (to me) is the contents of the `getFormatterClasses` function

```
class FieldFormatter{
    public static $exampleValues = '1234567890';
    public static function getFormatterClasses(){
        $classes = get_declared_classes();
        $subclasses = [];
        foreach($classes as $class){
            if(is_subclass_of($class, 'FieldFormatter')){
                $functions = get_class_methods($class);
                $functions = array_filter($functions, function($function){
                    return strpos($function, 'format') === 0;
                });
                $functionObjects = array_map(function($function) use ($class){
                    $pretty = str_replace('format', '', $function);

                    $exmapleValue =  is_array($class::$exampleValues) && isset($class::$exampleValues[$function]) ?
                     $class::$exampleValues[$function] : 
                     $class::$exampleValues;

                    $example = $class::$function($exmapleValue);
                    return [
                        'name' => $function,
                        'prettyName' => $pretty,
                        'example' => $example
                    
                    ];
                }, $functions);

                $subclasses[] = array(
                    'class' => $class,
                    'functions' => $functionObjects
                );
            }
        }
        return $subclasses;
    }
}

class TextFormatter extends FieldFormatter{
    public static $exampleValues = 'ABC123';
    public static function formatAlphaNumeric($value){
        return preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $value);
    }
    public static function formatAlpha($value){
        return preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', '', $value);
    }
    public static function formatNumeric($value){
        return preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $value);
    }
}

class CurrencyFormatter extends FieldFormatter{
    public static $exampleValues = '1000.00';
    public static function formatCurrency($value){
        return number_format($value, 2);
    }
    public static function formatCurrencyNoDecimal($value){
        return number_format($value, 0);
    }
}

class PhoneFormatter extends FieldFormatter{
    public static $exampleValues = '1234567890';
    public static function formatPhone($value){
        $value = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $value);
        $value = substr($value, 0, 10);
        $value = preg_replace('/^1?(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/', '($1) $2-$3', $value);
        return $value;
    }
    public static function formatPhonePlain($value){
        $value = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $value);
        $value = substr($value, 0, 10);
        return $value;
    }
    
}
```

Here is what the user input looks like.

[image]

Comment: It's not only that the code is ugly, you're also using the names of classes and methods directly in the output to the user. That's just weird. This has little to do with the original ideas behind OOP, or good programming practices, but I cannot argue with its effectiveness. Any solution, that adheres better to what is expected of programmers, would loose some of the advantages of your solution. That's probably why nobody has answered your question? I honestly think there is no possible answer to your question, because you could always argue that your solution satisfies your criteria better.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware yea i get you. Is there a particular reason using the Class names directly is a problem? I suppose I could put a space between the title cased parts, but does "weird" constitue "bad"? If so what are some alternatives. I think the design is just a carry over from C# desktop land.

Comment: I have a paradigm: _"Use things only for their intended purpose."_. Names of classes and methods exists to help a programmer understand the code, not to be sent to the site's user. What if you refactor your code? It'll be a mess. What if you want to translate the UI? It can't be done. In short: Misusing something often leads to inflexible code. Alternatives? Separate basis code, like formatters, from UI code, such as the input field. See: [Separation of Concerns](https://dev.to/tamerlang/separation-of-concerns-the-simple-way-4jp2). You probably don't need a class for each type of formatter.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i see what youre saying. the greater context is that it passes an array of all these formatters to the renderer view, which then the view builds the input based on that contetx, kind of how django or laravel does it. the only api the front end sees is that getFormatterClasses function so i dont super think there'd be any issues in the case of a refactor. I thought about using just a plain array with formatter names and the other things, but the implementation kind of got spread out, and the nice thing with this is that the internal implementation affects the "example" returned.

Comment: See, that's exactly the reaction I expected, and I fully understand why you're saying it. Still, I would never write, or accept, code like this in a project. I think the code for the list in the UI should be completely separate from the code for the basic formatting routines. Luckily we don't all have to do the same thing, and your code certainly does the job you expect of it.